# Strange behaviour of my javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Sorry for the vague title, but this behaviour is pretty hard to explain.

I have a form where I enter some information. When the user click the submit button (values "programma"), I call a javascript. I check that the info are correct and use AJAX to add a record in my local database. The strange behaviour is the following:

- I fill up the form. The record doesn't exist in my DB. Everything works correctly and my record is inserted. Success: I write in the span tag "Esecuzione registrata correttamente!"
- Then I try to insert the same record. Since it exists in my DB, the error gets notified correctly in my span: "Esiste un condannato con gli stessi dati"
- At this point my form is still full of text, if the user want to correct his mistake and insert a non-existing record. What happens is that, when I change some input (and I'm sure that record doesn't exist in my DB) and click the submit button, literally nothing happens. I still see my error message "Esiste un condannato con gli stessi dati", even if I saw in my console that my AJAX worked correctly

[image: Screenshot]

**programma.php** (what you see in my screenshot)

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION["nickname"]) && !isset($_SESSION["password"]) ) {
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p> Sessione di ".$_SESSION["nickname"]." con password ".$_SESSION["password"]." </p>";
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="programma.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            .container {
                width: 500px;
                clear: both;
            }
            .container text {
                width: 100%;
                clear: both;
            }
        </style>
      <title>RIPconvicts - Programma esecuzione</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php require 'snippets/menu.php'; ?>
        <form>
            <fieldset class="centered">
                <legend>Programma nuova esecuzione</legend>

                <label for="nome"> Nome* </label> <br>
                <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome"> <br> <br>

                <label for="cognome"> Cognome* </label> <br> 
                <input type="text" name="cognome" id="cognome"> <br> <br>

                <label for="classe"> Classe* </label> <br>
                <input type="text" name="classe" id="classe"> <br> <br>

                <label for="materia"> Materia* </label> <br>
                <input type="text" name="materia" id="materia"> <br> <br>

                <label for="data">Data* </label> <br>
                <input type="date" name="data" id="data"> <br> <br>

                Note <br>
                <textarea name="note" id="note" rows="6" cols="50"> </textarea> <br> <br>

                <span id="avviso" style="color:red"></span> <br>

                <input type="button" onclick="programma_esecuzione()" value="Programma">

            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <?php require 'snippets/footer.php'; ?>

        <script>
            function programma_esecuzione() {
                // Verifica che tutti i campi necessari siano stati riempiti
                document.getElementById("avviso").innerHTML = "";
                var nomi = ["nome", "cognome", "classe", "materia"];
                var campi_mancanti = "";

                for(var i=0; i<nomi.length-1; i++) {
                    if(document.getElementById(nomi[i]).value == "") {
                        campi_mancanti+=" "+nomi[i];
                    }
                }

                if(!Date.parse( document.getElementById("data").value )) {
                    campi_mancanti+=" data";
                }

                // Se ci sono campi mancanti, ritorna alla pagina principale
                if(campi_mancanti!="") {
                    window.alert("Riempire i seguenti campi mancanti:"+campi_mancanti);
                    return;
                }

                // Se tutti i campi necessari ci sono, allora è possibile richiedere l'aggiunta del record
                var xhttp;
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
                var cognome = document.getElementById("cognome").value;
                var classe = document.getElementById("classe").value;
                var materia = document.getElementById("materia").value;
                var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
                var note = document.getElementById("note").value;

                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        var risposta = this.responseText;

                        if(risposta.indexOf("Esecuzione registrata correttamente!") > -1) {

                            // Svuota tutti i campi
                            document.getElementById("nome").value = "";
                            document.getElementById("cognome").value = "";
                            document.getElementById("classe").value = "";
                            document.getElementById("materia").value = "";
                            document.getElementById("data").value = "";
                            document.getElementById("note").value = "";

                        }

                        document.getElementById("avviso").innerHTML = risposta;
                    }
                };

                xhttp.open("POST", "./snippets/programma_esecuzione.php", false);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhttp.send("nome="+nome+"&cognome="+cognome+"&classe="+classe+"&materia="+materia+"&data="+data+"&note="+note);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**programma_esecuzione.php** (where I execute my query)

```
<?php
    //Include
    require 'connetti_a_DB.php';

    // Variabili per il login
    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    $cognome = $_POST["cognome"];
    $classe = $_POST["classe"];
    $materia = $_POST["materia"];
    $data = $_POST["data"];
    $note = $_POST["note"];

    /*echo $nome."<br>";
    echo $cognome."<br>";
    echo $classe."<br>";
    echo $materia."<br>";
    echo $data."<br>";
    echo $note."<br>";*/

    // Inizia una sessione
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION["nickname"];
    $password = $_SESSION["password"];

    // Stabilire e chiudere connessione
    $conn = connetti_a_DB($username, $password);

        // Verifica se c'è un record "clone"
        $nome_completo = $nome." ".$cognome;
        $sql = " SELECT *
                FROM `lista`
                WHERE `NOME_COMPLETO`='$nome_completo' OR
                `CLASSE`='$classe' OR
                `MATERIA` ='$materia' OR
                `DATA` ='$data'";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo 'Esiste un condannato con gli stessi dati';
        }
        else
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `ripconvicts`.`lista` (`ID`, `NOME_COMPLETO`, `CLASSE`, `MATERIA`, `DATA`, `NOTE`)
                    VALUES (NULL, '$nome_completo', '$classe', '$materia', '$data', '$note')";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            echo "Esecuzione registrata correttamente!";
        }

    $conn->close();

    // Salta alla pagina iniziale
    //header("location: ../programma.php");
    //exit();
?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Are you sure the this.readyState is 4 and this.status 200 ??

Comment: Can you show me the screenshot of your response in console

Comment: The "Network" tab of the console will let you inspect the ajax requests / responses as they happen.  Verify that you are sending the form data you expect to send.  Then, verify that you are receiving the response you expect from your PHP script.

Click "XHR" filter to show only ajax network requests.

Comment: Everything was correct. So I thought that the only reason why I would receive that error, even if there was no record like that in my DB, was if my query was incorrect. It was so :|

**The correct one:**  (...) WHERE `NOME_COMPLETO`='$nome_completo' AND `CLASSE`='$classe' AND `MATERIA` ='$materia' AND `DATA` ='$data'"; 

**Not:** (...) WHERE `NOME_COMPLETO`='$nome_completo' OR `CLASSE`='$classe' OR `MATERIA` ='$materia' OR `DATA`